# How to filter a list inside Kotlin Flow

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I'm replacing my current implementation using `RxJava` to `Coroutines` and `Flow`. I'm having some trouble using some `Flow` operators.

I'm trying to filter the list of items inside a `Flow` before providing it to be collected. (`Flow<List<TaskWithCategory>>`)

Here is the example on `Rx2`:

```
        repository.findAllTasksWithCategory()
            .flatMap {
                Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                    .filter { item -> item.task.completed }
                    .toList()
                    .toFlowable()
```

In the implementation above, I provide a list of `TaskWithCategory` filtering by `Task`s that are already completed.

How can I achieve this using `Flow`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given that the only operator in use is `filter` the inner flowable is unnecessary, making the flow implementation quite straightforward:

```
repository.findAllTasksWithCategoryFlow()
    .map { it.filter { item -> item.task.completed } }
```

If the inner transformation is more involved (lets use `transform: suspend (X) -> TaskWithCategory`):

```
repository.findAllTasksWithCategoryFlow()
    // Pick according to desired backpressure behavior
    .flatMap(Latest/Concat/Merge) {
        // Scope all transformations together
        coroutineScope {
            it.map { item ->
                // Perform transform in parallel
                async {
                    transform(item)
                }
            }.awaitAll() // Return when all async are finished.
        }
    }
```

Comment: `flatMapMerge` works much simpler than you've shown, you need to provide a `Flow`-returning function and it will automatically parallelize the collection of these flows. `tasksFlow.flatMapMerge { flow { emit(it.map { transform(it) }) } }`

Comment: That would process different lists in parallel, while my version processes all items in a single list in parallel.

Comment: True, but processing each individual item in a separate coroutine is usually detrimental to performance, unless processing each item is really heavy. Also, in that case i don't think you're using `flatMapMerge` correctly, you make no use of the automatic concurrency it provides. You can get the same result with a plain `map` or `flatMap`.