# filter flowable list of object by category and group into another list of object in flow

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm, kotlin-stateflow

is it possible to filter and group `Flow<List<Object A>>`  by categories.

i found issue quite similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445105/how-to-filter-a-list-inside-kotlin-flow) , but no luck :(

here i'm sharing my approach which i tried,

code inside viewModel :

```
class HomeViewModel: ViewModel() {

 data class Car(val id: Int, val name: String, val category: Int)
 data class CarsByCategory(val categoryId:Int, val categoryName: String, val carList: List<Car>)

    private val categoryList =
        mapOf<Int, String>(1 to "Audi", 2 to "BMW", 3 to "Chevrolet", 4 to "Dodge", 5 to "Others")

    private val mutableCarList: MutableList<CarsByCategory> = mutableListOf()
    private val _mutableStateFlowCarList: MutableStateFlow<List<CarsByCategory>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    
    val filteredCarList: StateFlow<List<CarsByCategory>> = _mutableStateFlowCarList
    
    private fun getAllCarsAsFlow(): Flow<List<Car>> {
        val cars = listOf(
            Car(id = 1, name = "A1", category = 1),
            Car(id = 1, name = "A2", category = 1),
            Car(id = 1, name = "BMW X1", category = 2),
            Car(id = 1, name = "BMW X7", category = 2),
            Car(id = 1, name = "M Roadster", category = 2),
            Car(id = 1, name = "Bolt EUV", category = 3),
            Car(id = 1, name = "Blazer", category = 3),
            Car(id = 1, name = "Challenger", category = 4),
            Car(id = 1, name = "Neon", category = 4),
            Car(id = 1, name = "Frontier", category = 5)
        )
        return flowOf(cars)
    }
  
   private fun filterCarByCategory(){
        getAllCarsAsFlow().map { carList ->
            for (key in categoryList.keys) {
                val filteredList = carList.filter { car -> car.category == key }
                mutableCarList.add(
                    CarsByCategory(
                        categoryId = key,
                         categoryName= categories.getValue(key),
                        carList = filteredList
                    )
                )
            }
            _mutableStateFlowCarList.value = mutableCarList.toList()
        }
    }

    init {
        filterCarByCategory()
    }
}
```

code in  fragment:

```
  ....

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            homeViewModel.filteredCarList.collect {
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${it.size}")
//                here getting car list size is 0
            }
        }
    }

  ...
```

i don't know is it right approach or not , please let me know how to solve this problem using flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flow doesn't emit any value until it is collected. So you need to collect your flow:

```kotlin
private fun filterCarByCategory(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        getAllCarsAsFlow().collect { carList ->
            // Rest everything same
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** If the sole purpose of `_mutableStateFlowCarList` is to provide data to UI, you need not use a `StateFlow` here, just a normal `Flow` would do the job.

```kotlin
val filteredCarList = getAllCarsAsFlow().map { carList ->
    categoryList.map { (id, name) ->
        CarsByCategory (
            categoryId = id,
            categoryName = name,
            carList = carList.filter { car -> car.category == id }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: that's True, But Can we Convert Existing Data Stream Flow into Another Type Which contains Filtered List as per our requirement and then collect  on UI Screen instead on ViewModel. i mean is there any easy approach for  doing same thing using flow?

Comment: Is there any special reason for using `StateFlow`? Why not a normal `Flow`? A normal `Flow` can be generated by using the `map` operator which you can then collect in your UI.

Comment: Also, the code I wrote above still uses `_mutableStateFlowCarList` which you can collect in the UI (as you are doing now). Only change was to replace `map` with `collect`.

Comment: i don't thing so, can we emit mutableCarList value on outer flow or do we need to create another flow for it?

Comment: `val filteredCarList = getAllCarsAsFlow().map { carList -> // Return filtered list here }` This will give you a `Flow` which you can then collect in your UI.

Comment: can you please share your code  implementation.

Comment: But @Arpit Shukla here we filter List inside for loop as per requirement, your code block works for filter list of one category only not list of categories

Comment: See the edit I just made.

Comment: Also, in your original code, you weren't clearing `mutableCarList` anywhere. Was that on purpose?

Comment: Thanks @Arpit Shukla, your edit code working fine and `mutableCarList` not in used anymore ,so i removed it.

Comment: since `val filteredCarList` is Flow and it's inside `private fun filterCarByCategory()` which is called in viewModel's `init` block. so how i can collect it from UI i think we need `MutableStateFlow` for it or Do you have any better way please share it BTW i'm new it flow.

Comment: Don't put it inside `filterCarByCategory()`, let it be at the top level. And you can remove that `init` block also.